# Wrap outgoing emails in HTML table in Exchange Online (server-side)

Tags: email, exchange

I was trying to wrap all outgoing emails with (and then centerize it for client mails, not shown here):

```
<HTML> 
    <TABLE>
        <TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <TR>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD width="400">
                **CONTENT GOES HERE**
            </TD>
            <TD></TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</HTML>
```

...using Exchange transport rules.

First I've setup disclaimer rule to check if HTML even works. Surely it does and I managed to make either footer or header that is centerized in table tag.

Based on that I've tried to basically cut HTML given above in half and prepend message with 1st half, and make footer with 2nd half, effectively "wrapping" message with HTML table.

This doesnt work, as apparently html tags opend by prepend rule are auto-closed before message is placed, so that footer rule does nothing (it's a separate html block).

Is there a way to somehow wrap outgoing mail in HTML on server side? Maybe there are some special cmds in powershell that would allow configuring it on Exchange?

Comment: Hi, is there any update? Please check if the below info is helpful to you. If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, if we created a prepend disclaimer(with the content) and an append one(with a footer) in the same rule, the previous disclaimer will be replaced with the latter one:

1. View the parameters "**ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText**" and "**ApplyHtmlDisclaimerLocation**" after adding an append disclaimer:

[image]

2. Add another prepend disclaimer:

[image]

3. View the transport rule and parameters after adding the prepend disclaimer:

[image]

If you used this method to add disclaimers and the message didn't apply the 2rd added disclaimer, the issue could be caused by the above reason(The latter disclaimer will replace the previous one, this can be reflected in the parameters of the transport rule), and there seems no parameters could combine the two disclaimer methods.

Comment: Sorry for long silence! Okay, so I think You didn't understand my problem. Before going into that - I really appreciate Your input, because it solves my other problem (with trying to do 2 prepend and append together in one rule). As to this topic - my question was how to WRAP the message written by email client with HTML tags so that I can basically make whole client-written email centerized on receiver email client. I was trying to do it with prepend and append, but html tags are auto-closed (so that I can't open one in prepend and close it in append to manipulate message content). Solutions?

Comment: Maybe you could create a .html file which includes the HTML tags and info you want to add, then use IE to send page by email(https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-send-a-complete-webpage-by-email/), after sending a new email, not only the html tags in .html file but also the mail flow will be triggered.